# Jersey rest api com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerExceptionServlet

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey, tomcat6

I am new to creating API's. I found what I thought was a simple example online but was unable to get it to work. Any help or advice would be great.

This is my web.xml file

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">

<display-name>Hello, World Application</display-name>
<description>
This is a simple web application with a source code organization
based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
</description>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GetEDPInfo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>mypackage</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetEDPInfo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GetEDPInfo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my java example GetEDPInfo.java

```
package mypackage;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/GetEDPInfo")
public class GetEDPInfo {

@GET
@Path("/{param}")
public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
String output = "Welcome"+ msg;
return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}

}
```

I downloaded these jar files and placed them in my WEB-INF/lib directory 
asm-3.1.jar, jersey-core-1.8.jar, jersey-server-1.8.jar
not sure if I need more than that, but those were all the ones used on the example i looked at.

I compiled my java file with the following command:
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 -bootclasspath /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/rt.jar cp .:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/sample/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-core-1.8:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/sample/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-server-1.8:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/sample/WEB-INF/lib/asm-3.1 GetEDPInfo.java

That created my class file with no errors.

When i navigate to http://grv4:8080/sample/GetEDPInfo
i get this message...

```
HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

type Status report

message Method Not Allowed

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Method Not Allowed).
```

When I navigate to http://grv4:8080/sample/GetEDPInfo/Jeeves
i get this message...

```
HTTP Status 404 - /sample/GetEDPInfo/Jeeves

type Status report

message /sample/GetEDPInfo/Jeeves

description The requested resource (/sample/GetEDPInfo/Jeeves) is not available.
```

This is my modified code...

```
package mypackage;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/GetEDPInfo")
public class GetEDPInfo {

@GET
@Path("/{param}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
String output = "Welcome"+ msg;
return output;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `<param-value>mypackage.GetEDPInfo</param-value>` to following and it should work `<param-value>mypackage</param-value>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your suggestion but that gives me a Status 405 Method not allowed error message. My url is http://grv4:8080/sample/GetEDPInfo

Comment: Please try this url and share your output `grv4:8080/sample/GetEDPInfo/jeeves` because as per your java class there is no method with default GET implementation.

Comment: I updated my post to show the correct "mypackage" in the xml file and displayed the error messages I get when I go to the url.

Comment: Can you try following method and check whether its returning proper result

`@GET`
`@Path("/{param}")`
`@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`
`@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`
`public String getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {`
`String output = "Welcome"+ msg;`
`return output;`
`}`

Comment: I posted the updated java file. I compiled it the same way i did before, then restarted tomcat. Still get the same error messages as before when navigating to the url. Let me know if you have any other ideas, Thanks

Comment: Sorry nothing else comes to my mind right now, you can view this tutorial, this might help [link](http://www.javabrains.io)

Comment: I accepted this answer because Singh gave me some helpful tips and pointed out some errors that got me closer to getting the application to work

Comment: Thanks @jeeves2007.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working, for some reason I needed to change my web.xml file to use /* as my url pattern...

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>GetEDPInfo</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```